# How to specify non-default public folders

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to create a macro, that allows for copying currently selected folder into a public (shared) folder.

```
Sub CopyFolder()
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInboxFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myToBeCopiedFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim TopPublicFolder As Object

    Set TopPublicFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders)
    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInboxFolder = TopPublicFolder.Folders("Office emails")
    Set myToBeCopiedFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set myNewFolder = myContactsFolder.CopyTo(myInboxFolder)
End Sub
```

[image: How my public folders look]

Currently, I am getting run-time error 91, and to be honest, no idea why.

Comment: Set myNameSpace before Set TopPublicFolder

Comment: Your suggestion with the mistake spotted by Eugene, fixed it for me thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `myContactsFolder` object declared in the code:

```
Sub CopyFolder()
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myInboxFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myToBeCopiedFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim TopPublicFolder As Object

Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set TopPublicFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders)
Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInboxFolder = TopPublicFolder.Folders("Office emails")
Set myToBeCopiedFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
Set myNewFolder = myToBeCopiedFolder.CopyTo(myInboxFolder)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake. though i am still getting an error and when I press debug it highlights the 
Set TopPublicFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders)